# Calculating Average of 7 Numbers in Python

Tags: python, average

```
x = int(input())
Count = 0
Sum = 0
Average = 0
for i in range(7):
    Sum = Sum + x
    Count = Count + 1
else:
    Average= Sum/Count
    print("The sum is",Sum)
    print("The average is",Average)
```

Trying to calculate average with this code of 7 numbers but unable to reach the last few lines.
Any help would be gladly appreciated!

Comment: This will not be 7 different numbers, it just calculates the sum and average of the same `x` 7 times.

Comment: The is a special function in Python `mean()`.

Comment: I presume that `else` statement is causing an error as well because you don't have an accompanying `if` statement?

Comment: This should actually work, although `for`/`else` is an uncommon pattern and not needed at all here. You can just remove the `else` and unindent everything after it. (Note that, as @Phydeaux says, this won't calculate the average of 7 different numbers, all 7 will be the one number entered by the user).

Comment: Did you mean to have `x = int(input())` inside the for loop?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to ask the user for 7 different inputs (rather than calculating the average of the same number 7 times), give this a try, using list comprehension and the built-in functions `sum` and `len` to compute the mean:

```
num_values = 7

values_list = [int(input("Enter a number: ")) for _ in range(num_values)]

average = sum(values_list) / len(values_list)

print("The average is {}".format(average))
```

Alternatively, if you *do* want to calculate the average of the same number X times:

```
value = int(input("Enter a number: "))

print("The average is {}".format(value))
```